# How to pass multiple arrays in RecyclerAdapter in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, parsing, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I want to bring in recycler_item.xml information from multiple arrays
Arrays

> newstitl.add(i, titl);
>
> newsdat.add(i, dat);
>
> newsbody.add(i, body);

positioning in

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/tv_recycler_item"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
/>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/tv_recycler_item1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
/>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/tv_recycler_item2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
/>
```

In NewsFragment.java

```
mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) viiew.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(newstitl);
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

There RecyclerAdapter.java

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<String> mDataset;

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView mTextView;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            mTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_recycler_item);
        }
    }

    public RecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<String> dataset) {
        mDataset = dataset;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.recycler_item, parent, false);

        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.mTextView.setText(mDataset.get(position));

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }

}
```

While I was able to take only one array
[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U32fv.jpg)

Comment: @OlehKykena
How do I create this model from an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, you just need to make a few adjustments to your adapter.. What you need is an adapter that accepts 3 ArrayList..

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<String> mDataset;
    private ArrayList<String> mDataset2;
    private ArrayList<String> mDataset3;

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView mTextView, mTextView2, mTextView3 ;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            mTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_recycler_item);
            mTextView2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_recycler_item1);
            mTextView3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_recycler_item2);
        }
    }

    public RecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<String> dataset, ArrayList<String>dataset2, ArrayList<String>dataset3) {
        mDataset = dataset;
        mDataset2 = datset2;
        mDataset3 = dataset3;

    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.recycler_item, parent, false);

        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.mTextView.setText(mDataset.get(position));
        holder.mTextView1.setText(mDataset2.get(position));
        holder.mTextView.setText(mDataset3.get(position));    
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }

}
```

And Call the 3 ArrayList adapter Constructor in your NewsFragment like this -

```
mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) viiew.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(newstitl,newsdat, newsbody);
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create some model called, for example,  `News` which contains date, title and body. Then you should pass `List<News>` to your adapter instead of `List<String>` and manipulate your data as you like.